# Number of combinations possible for 2 out of 3 product options on 5 machines.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I don't know how that problem would be called, feel free to change the title accordingly.

I have five machines that each can produce three different kind of products, A, B and C. How many combinations are there

- in total?
- to produce exactly two different kinds?

My guess:

$3^5 = 243$ possible combinations in total.

$3$ possible combinations of two kinds (AB, AC, BC) , each with $2^5$ possibilities. We need to substract the $3$ combinations of all machines producing the same product.

$3\cdot2^5-3=93$ possible combinations of exactly two kinds

Here's where my textbook says otherwise: It says the solution is

$3(2^5-2)=90$

This would mean for each AB, AC and BC, there are two combinations of just one product being manufactured. But in my understanding, when I look at AB, the combination [A,A,A,A,A] and [B,B,B,B,B] gets substracted, obviously. But why would, for example, the same combination [A,A,A,A,A] be substracted another time in the case of AC?

If I would write all $243$ possible combinations down, there are only three cases in which only one product would be produced: either all A, B or C.

Is my textbook wrong, or am I?

Thanks for your help, sorry if the question is a bit trivial for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have all the right ideas. Let's try to understand the textbook's answer first:

*There are $3(2^5-2)$ combinations:*

Let's pick $AB$ as one of our three pair of products to produce. Then as you have put it, there are $2^5$ ways the machine can produce a combination of $A$'s or $B$'s. In particular, there is one way all machines can produce $A's$, and one way all machines can produce $B$'s, so we need to subtract $2$ from our answer, that is $2^5-2$. We do this for each possible pair $AB$, $BC$ or $CA$, to obtain $3(2^5-2)$. We need to check that any combination we get from $AB$, say, is not the same as any combination we get from $BA$, and so on. i.e we don't want to **overcount** any combination we are interested in. This should be straightforward.

Let's understand why your solution was wrong.

You suggest that in total there are $3\cdot 2^5$ ways to produce a combination of either $AB$, $BC$ or $CA$, but then we need to subtract the cases where we produce $[A, A, A, A, A]$ or $[B, B, B, B, B]$ or $[C, C, C, C, C]$. Up to here I completely agree with your method. But **how many times did we count $[A, A, A, A, A]$?** When we looked at the $AB$ case, we counted $[A, A, A, A, A]$ once. When we looked at $CA$, we counted it once more. So we actually counted $[A, A, A, A, A]$ twice! i.e we need to subtract $2$ from $3 \cdot 2^5$. Similarly, we subtract $2$ for each $[B, B, B, B, B]$ and $[C, C, C, C, C]$, so we get $3\cdot 2^5 -6=3\cdot(2^5-2)$.

If you're worried about overcounting any other combination (e.g have we counted $[A, B, B, B, B]$ too many times?), you can check (as before) that no other combination is counted too many times.